# SQL Server 2016 removes leading zero on FORMAT compared to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server

We are testing moving our Data Warehouse onto SQL Server 2016 from SQL Server 2012.

One thing I've noticed in generating our date dimension is that the following produces different results:
`FORMAT(DateList.CalendarDate, 'M', 'en-gb')`

SQL Server 2012 has a leading zero where as 2016 does not:
`01 January` vs `1 January`

Any idea why this is? Is there a setting for this? Id prefer not to have to change any code that use this function.

Comment: Did you try `SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'M', 'en-gb') AS 'Great Britain English Result' `  in SQL Server 2016?

Comment: Honestly, I wouldn't use `FORMAT()`, stick to tried and true `CONVERT()` methods (even if they are more cumbersome). [Here's why](https://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but). Otherwise, try `'dd MMMM'` instead of `'M'`. Again, more cumbersome, but not prone to regional settings and other external influence.

Comment: Yep not ideal but was trying to avoid having to make any unplanned changes. Found out that it was only used in a few places so changed to `DATENAME(month...`.. just curious why the difference in functionality between the two instances (which are on the same server so I don't think its regional settings).